# Stackexchange, Can't log in?

Tags: bug, login, openid

I was trying to log in to my stack overflow account - (using facebook, google, stackexchange etc) - I kept getting "Logging in, you are being redirected vexe..." - (or something similar) - and the page just kept getting refreshed without anything happening.

I don't know if I should be asking this here, I don't know if there's a more suitable place.

The only way I managed to log in, is via creating a meta stackoverflow account which I didn't have previously.

Why is this happening and how to avoid it? Is this a bug or...? and why does not any of the stack exchange sites let me sign in normally without signing in using facebook or google, etc? (ie. just a normal username, pass)

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Just great! I thought that logging into one stack exchange, would gain me access to all my other accounts. But it seems that I must sign in to each one individually in order to get it. (I was writing a question in english.stackexchange, I couldn't post it cause I can't seem to log in no matter what).... I can't log into anything now unless I create a new account! :( Anybody?

Comment: Vexe, do you happen to use CCleaner from piriform? The issue you are describing - autologin not working - remembers me of a similar problem related to the CCleaner clean function

Comment: Also - you have a single account for all the sites you are trying to access, right?

Comment: About your first question: I do use some cleaning softwares like Tune up utilities. I used to use CCleaner from time to time... But I can't remember if I ever used it after I did a fresh install of Windows, a couple of months ago. But what I do remember is, as I mentioned before, I used to use CCleaner regularly, but I never had a problem with signing in due to using it.

Comment: About your 2nd: well, it should be one account yes. Which means, I 'should' be able to access them all if I signed into one of them, right? But here I am, signed into meta, but yet can't access any of the others....

Comment: Yep, just checked your account from the profile page. You should be able to log on the other sites. As I said, I had a similar problem after CCleaner somehow managed to damage some files in the isolated storage. Could you try to clean all saved history/temp files/cookies from your browser and then retry to log?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that the issue is related to the browser I'm using. I was using firefox but just downloaded chrome and I was able to sign in. But strange thing though, before I tried chrome I DID clear the cache in firefox and whatnot... but didn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: OK scratch that - never mind. I had to clear EVERYTHING not just the cache. Thanks for the help. If you want, post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Are you per chance using Firefox, if so what version? You might be hitting a known quirk.

Comment: Yes I am using Firefox 26.0, which is from what I know the most up-to-date version...

Comment: @Tiny sounds like a browser/cleaning utility combo, not something very common. Still, might be good to add some sanity check to the code and identify such endless login redirect loop then show a message "Please clear your cache and try again". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem showing up after CCleaner decided to clean up only some of the files in the isolated storage / temp internet files directory. From what I had understood, he managed to put the login cookies in a state where the site saw me as unlogged, but I was already logged for the login procedure.

Saving other tech details and the fun I had trying to discover that... what I did in the end was just cleaning up all the cache/browsing history/temp file from IE. Try a full clean and you should be fine. Also - use IE menu (or your selected browser ones), not a CCleaner clean.